# How to build a AlertDialog that looks like a Leanback GuidedStepFragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles, leanback

I made an Android application that supports Leanback ( Or in other words it works on Android TV), when I build an `AlertDialog` with the styles `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` and `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK` ( depending on night mode ) and show it it looks like the native `AlertDialog` seen on Phones/Tablets
[image: A native AlertDialog]

What I want to achieve is to make that `AlertDialog` look like a `GuidedStepFragment` ( shown in the image below )
[image: A GuidedStepFragment]

Is there is any way to achieve that like a style other than `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` and `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`, a class that extends `AlertDialog.Builder` or by using a custom view like the code below for example?

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(DialogStyles.this);
        final View DialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom, null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogStyles.this).create();
        dialog.setView(DialogView);
```

Comment: `AlertDialog` is completely different from `GuidedStepFragment`. You can simply add this fragment to your activity instead of using `AlertDialog`, But changing styles won't help.

Comment: First, I know that ```AlertDialog``` and ```GuidedStepFragment``` are different, but I just wanted a way to make ```AlertDialog``` mimic ```GuidedStepFragment```s, I also don't want to add ```GuidedStepFragment```s to my activity since it's more complicated and I prefer to use ```AlertDialog```s since I'm used to them, I also think that making an ```AlertDialog``` that mimics ```GuidedStepFragment```s is possible, probably by making a fullscreen dialog with a custom view.

Comment: `GuidedStepFragment` inflates [lb_guidedstep_fragment.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ce0bd5a/v17/leanback/res/layout/lb_guidedstep_fragment.xml) which has two simple `FrameLayout`s: one for guidance and another for actions. For guidance view take a look at [lb_guidance.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ce0bd5a/v17/leanback/res/layout/lb_guidance.xml) and for actions use [lb_guidedactions.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ce0bd5a/v17/leanback/res/layout/lb_guidedactions.xml).

Comment: That didn't work for me, but I hope that someone uses these layouts as a reference and makes a custom layout that can be used with ```AlertDialog```,It'll help a lot.